# Best Practice to store Salesforce credentials outside Salesforce for Python Integration

Tags: integration, developer, python, website-integration

At the moment, I'm using Python to integrate one of our databases into Salesforce using [simple-salesforce](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/) package, and at the moment, all the Salesforce credentials are stored in the code itself.

Is there a best practice or the best place to store the salesforce credentials outside of salesforce so that the credentials are encrypted?

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/09/how-to-automate-data-extraction-from-salesforce-using-python

Comment: I would not recommend to use `UserName` and `Password` flow for connecting via `simple-salesforce`. Instead use `session_id` and `instance_url`. You can generate the session id via "Client Credentials Flow" provided by salesforce.  And save the client ClientId and ClientSecret in some secure server. Securely storing this clientId and clientsecret will fall outside of this site scope and can be generally asked in stackexhange.

Comment: thanks @NagendraSingh! can you walk me through how to get the session_id? I checked online and couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: @jackson https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_client_credentials_flow.htm&type=5